# Unknown type 'AppBarButton' in XML namespace - Windows 8 Store App XAML, issues adding app bars

Tags: xaml, windows-8, namespaces, winrt-xaml

I'm new to developing Windows 8 apps, and am having trouble getting my XAML file to recognise generated code for adding AppBars and CommandBars.

I am getting the error "Unknown type [something] in XML namespace" for a number of elements I am trying to add, here is my example below:

[image: Unknown type 'AppBarButton' in XML Namespace]

If I re-open my solution this is temporarily displayed as a warning rather than an error. Also navigating to http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation just produces "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.".

This is all default code. my class namespace (e.g. MyApp.MainPage) matches the MainPage code behind namespace. I am at a loss and have been battling this for hours. I also intermittently changes from this error to 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context". I have spent hours on XAML permissions errors in the past few days and don't want to waste any more time with errors in default generated code! :(

EDIT: I have tried this on three different machines, using both Windows 8 and Windows 8.1, both new projects and the existing project I have described in this post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is that you are using Visual Studio 2012 (Windows 8 apps). If so, you should use [Button](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.button.aspx):

```
<Page.TopAppBar>
    <AppBar>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Style="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}">A</Button>
            <Button Style="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}">B</Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </AppBar>
</Page.TopAppBar>
```

To use [AppBarButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.appbarbutton.aspx), you must use Visual Studio 2013 (Windows 8.1 apps):

```
<Page.TopAppBar>
    <AppBar>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <AppBarButton>
                <AppBarButton.Icon>
                    <FontIcon Glyph="A"/>
                </AppBarButton.Icon>
            </AppBarButton>
            <AppBarButton>
                <AppBarButton.Icon>
                    <FontIcon Glyph="B"/>
                </AppBarButton.Icon>
            </AppBarButton>
        </StackPanel>
    </AppBar>
</Page.TopAppBar>
```

Also, [CommandBars](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.commandbar.aspx) are only available in Windows 8.1.

Comment: This would appear to have been the problem. As the AppBarButton came up with IntelliSense, I assumed it was usable, however I did not realise there was a difference between Windows 8 and Windows 8.1 apps.  I have to continue to use VS2012 as required by uni. Thanks.