# Unknown type 'AppBarButton' in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'

Tags: xaml, uwp

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrpjQ.png)

Unknown type 'AppBarButton' in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce the error with Visual Studio 2015 and Visual Studio 2017 by UWP app. I guess you are using Visual Studio 2012 and developing Windows 8 app.

If in that case, you may need to use Visual Studio 2013 or higher and developing a windows 8.1 app or higher. It seems like [`AppBarButton`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.appbarbutton) is not supported in windows phone 8. More details please reference [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19801040/unknown-type-appbarbutton-in-xml-namespace-windows-8-store-app-xaml-issues).

By the way, you may need to detail your question about what you want to ask. Details please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).